# Rails 5.2- Cannot access calling controller method from within respond_to block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this method in my application controller which renders the view template for the corresponding user type.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def render_for_user
    view = caller_locations.first.label
    if current_user.blank?
      render "#{view}_guest"
    else
      render "#{view}_#{current_user.role.downcase}"
    end
  end
end
```

And I call this method in the following fashion:

```
Class CommentController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    render_for_user
  end
end
```

Where I run into trouble, is calling this method from inside of a `respond_to` block. Here is an example:

```
Class CommentController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { render_for_user }
    end
  end
end
```

Since the controller method in the application controller just fetches the name of the calling method one step up, it's defeated by the respond_to block.

My question is this: looking at the above code, is there a better, more flexible way to obtain the calling controller method?

Comment: You need to make the `CommentController` inherit from `ApplicationController` and not `ActionController::Base` for that to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is this: looking at the above code, is there a better, more flexible way to obtain the calling controller method?

`controller_name` will return `name.demodulize.sub(/Controller$/, '').underscore` which is probably want you want. I've never seen someone need to use caller_location. Similarly there's `action_name`

There's also `params[:controller]` and `params[:action]`